# Как дополнить отрисовку поля ColorBlock в редакторе?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Хочу сделать кнопки, позволяющие копировать/вставлять struct `ColorBlock` (находится в базовом `UnityEngine.UI.Selectable`).

Для начала попытался переопределить редактор компонента `Button`. Ожидал чего-то подобного:

[image: моё представление того, как это должно выглядеть]

Однако, столкнулся с тем, что редактор `Button`, будто "непереопределяем". Т.е. написанный мною кастомный редактор игнорируется и компонент кнопки в инспекторе рисуется по-старому. Код этого кастомного редактора:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Button))]
public class ButtonEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawCopyPasteButtons();
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
    }

    void DrawCopyPasteButtons()
    {
        if (GUILayout.Button("copy colors"))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

**Вопрос**: что я делаю не так и как я могу добиться желаемого результата (дополнить отрисовку `Color` кнопками copy-paste)? **Важно сохранить независимость от `Button`** для ситуаций, когда понадобится скопировать цветовой блок из кнопки, например, в `Toggle` (который тоже наследуется от `Selectable`).

*p.s.* пробовал также через `PropertyDrawer` (т.е. не кастомный отрисовщик редактора кнопки, а кастомный отрисовщик именно поля с цветами), но затем понял, что `ColorBlock` - это не `[SerializeField]`-поле, а свойство и значит его нельзя так отрисовать (я ведь верно понял, что `PropertyDrawer` работает только с `[SerializeField]`-полями?...)

*p.p.s* если инспектор переопределить нельзя, можно ли как-то прицепиться к контекстному меню компонента кнопки? (`[ContextMenu("Copy")]`)

---

**UPD:** всё-таки мне удалось реализовать желанное копирование цвета через кастомную отрисовку поля типа `Color`. Код с комментариями вынесен в ответ ниже. За содействие в решении благодарю пользователя [M. Green](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/252776/m-green).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать копирование цвета с помощью `CustomPropertyDrawer` для поля типа `Color`. За содействие в решении благодарю пользователя [M. Green](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/252776/m-green).

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Color), true)]
public class ColorPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    //просто для красоты, чтобы кнопки были малых размеров
    GUIStyle _copyButtonStyle;

    //статическое поле, где будет храниться скопированный цвет
    public static Color CopiedCollorBuffer;

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        CheckButtonStyle();

        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(property);
        CheckDrawPasteButton(property);
        DrawCopyButton(property);

        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    //метод проверки наполненности буффера и отрисовки кнопки вставки
    //(если пуст - т.е. цвет не копировали - кнопка "←" не рисуется)
    void CheckDrawPasteButton(SerializedProperty property)
    {
        //если буффер не пустой, т.е. цвет копировали
        if (CopiedCollorBuffer != null)
        {
            //рисуем кнопку "←"
            if (GUILayout.Button("←", _copyButtonStyle))
            {
                //при нажатии кнопки
                //заменяем цвет на хранящийся в нашем буффере
                property.colorValue = CopiedCollorBuffer;
            }
        }
    }

    //метод отрисовки кнопки копирования
    void DrawCopyButton(SerializedProperty property)
    {
        //рисуем кнопку "©"
        if (GUILayout.Button("©", _copyButtonStyle))
        {
            //при нажатии кнопки
            //сохраняем скопированный цвет в наш буффер
            CopiedCollorBuffer = property.colorValue;
        }
    }

    //просто для красоты, чтобы кнопки были малых размеров
    void CheckButtonStyle()
    {
        if (_copyButtonStyle == null)
        {
            _copyButtonStyle = new GUIStyle("Button");
            _copyButtonStyle.fixedWidth = 30;
            _copyButtonStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
            _copyButtonStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: теперь мои поля Color рисуются так]

Comment: Спрашивали одно, ответ про другое, вы хоть для будущих вопрошающих поясните в вопросе, что вам в итоге нужно было сделать.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker каюсь, заголовок вопроса отредактировать забыл. Но, по-вашему, первая строчка - "Хочу сделать кнопки, позволяющие копировать/вставлять struct ColorBlock" - недостаточно прозрачно поясняет мои цели? Да и "UPD:" я внизу вопроса сразу же дописал. Если вас так волнует судьба этого вопроса, будьте добры, предложите свою формулировку, более понятную для будущих вопрошающих.

Comment: "Как дополнить редактор Button", в итоге ответ переопределяет вообще все цветовые поля во всем движке. Посмотрите на свой скриншот, а потом посмотрите на результат. Да и с каких пор гуглят по содержанию вопроса, а не по заголовку?

Answer (score 1):

Unity позволяет изменять далеко не все редакторы своих компонентов, способов обойти это ограничение 2:

1. унаследоваться от компонента UI.Button и ничего не менять в этом классе, а вот уже редактор своей кнопки переопределить, как угодно;
2. написать с нуля свое окно инспектора, который уже будет по вашему велению отрисовывать компоненты объекта;

Comment: "...далеко не все редакторы своих компонентов..." - а какие изменять всё-таки можно? или хотя бы подскажите, как эту тему лучше гуглить - что-то типа "overriding basic editors components unity"?

Comment: @MikhailDeyman я вам написал, как можно переопределить стандартные редакторы в первом варианте, в гугле вы другого ответа не найдете. Полного списка переопределяемых компонентов я вам не дам, максимум знаю про `Transform` - его можно переопределить без всяких плясок с бубном.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так можно написать кастомный редактор не к компоненту `Button`, а к вашему компоненту ~`ButtonColorCopy`, который обращается к компоненту `Button`. Ваш класс будет иметь поле `static Button Sample;`, которое вы определяете при `copy` и копируете набор цветов из него при `paste` на другом экземпляре.

Однако есть вариант лучше и без кастумных редакторов и без нужды множества `paste`. Создайте `Prefab` с компонетом `Button` который будет служить стилем. И скрипт с полем `public Button Style;` принимающий те или иные стили, который вы накинете ко всем ваши кнопкам и он будет копировать набор цветов с вашего префаба при запуске, после чего `Destroy(self);` за дальнейшей ненадобностью.